# How to modify a setter from code behind in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I tried to modify a background property alone in a Style from code behind for some internal purpose in my WPF application, below error thrown when try to add a new setter to the style that we used

`After a 'SetterBase' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified.`

How can i resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

if you have something along the lines of:

```
<Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Red" />
```

this can be replaced using the code behind. In C#, that would look like this:

```
var setter = new Setter
{
  Property = Button.BackgroundProperty,
  Value = "red",
};
```

Or, using bindings:

```
Value = new Binding("BackgoundColour"),
```

where BackgroundColour is a variable.

I am not sure if this works when the base is sealed, but try it.

Comment: Besides writing `Value = Brushes.Red` instead of `Value = "red"`, also make sure to actually replace the existing Setter by the new one.

Comment: forgot about the brushes haha. I am new to WPF so don't assume i'm 100% correct